# Returning a collection of interfaces

Tags: java, generics

I have created the following interface

```
public interface ISolutionSpace {
  public boolean isFeasible();
  public boolean isSolution();
  public Set<ISolutionSpace> generateChildren();
}
```

However, in the implementation of `ISolutionSpace` in a class called `EightQueenSolutionSpace`, I am going to return a set of `EightQueenSolutionSpace` instances, like the following stub:

```
@Override
public Set<ISolutionSpace> generateChildren() {
  return new HashSet<EightQueenSolutionSpace>();
}
```

However this stub wont compile. What changes do I need to make?

EDIT: I tried 'HashSet' as well and had tried using the extends keyword. However since 'ISolutionSpace' is an interface and `EightQueenSolutionSpace` is an implementation(and not a subclass) of 'ISolutionSpace', it is still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return new HashSet<ISolutionSpace>();
```

All the references in the HashSet can point to EightQueenSolutionSpace instances, but the generic type should be ISolutionSpace.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if I was getting the list of instances from somewhere else, what other choice I would have except for creating a new collection and casting?

Answer (score 10):

Two possibilities:

```
@Override
public Set<? extends ISolutionSpace> generateChildren() {
  return new HashSet<EightQueenSolutionSpace>();
}
```

Or

```
@Override
public Set<ISolutionSpace> generateChildren() {
  return new HashSet<ISolutionSpace>();
}
```

and simply add instances of EightQueenSolutionSpace to the set.

Comment: As I said above, Eight... is not a subclass, but an implementation of ISolutionSpace, so the extends trick won't work.

Comment: ? extends X is a bounded wildcard for generics. X is simply the upper bound of the wildcard, and even though the keyword is extends it can be an interface or a class.

Answer (score 3):

Mind you, inheritance and other object hierarchy features don't exactly work like expected in generics.

But it's not your only problem : you try to return an `ArrayList` as an implementation of `Set`, which can't work !

Concerning the generics part, when you write `Set<ISolutionSpace>`, you say to the compiler you want a collection of instances of `ISolutionSpace`, but not of possible subclasses of `ISolutionSpace`. To be allowed to use subclasses, you'll have to use `? extends ISolutionSpace`, which precisely says "accept any subclass of ISolutionSpace".

So, to have a valid code, you'll have to change both your interface and your implementation.

Your interface should become

```
public interface ISolutionSpace {
  public boolean isFeasible();
  public boolean isSolution();
  public Set<? extends ISolutionSpace> generateChildren();
}
```

And your implementation

```
@Override
public Set<? extends ISolutionSpace> generateChildren() {
  //for()
  return new HashSet<EightQueenSolutionSpace>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set and List are different types of collections.

You could either change your declaration to return a list, or change the return parameter class to an implementation of Set (HashSet, TreeSet...)

Answer (score 0):

According to the Java API:

> Interface Set
>
> All Superinterfaces: Collection
> All Known Subinterfaces: SortedSet All
>
> Known Implementing Classes:
> AbstractSet, HashSet, LinkedHashSet,
> TreeSet

I think you have to replace Set with List:

> Interface List
>
> All Superinterfaces: Collection
>
> All
> Known Implementing Classes:
> AbstractList, ArrayList, LinkedList,
> Vector

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the caller would in turn work with the generic `ISolutionSpace` interface rather than the specific `EightQueenSolutionSpace`, just change the `generateChildren` method to `public Set<? extends ISolutionSpace> generateChildren()`

Answer (score 0):

All the types of collection in Java is like this:

```
Collection
├List
│  ├LinkedList
│  ├ArrayList
│  └Vector
│　    └Stack
└Set
Map
├Hashtable
├HashMap
└WeakHashMap
```

So it's obvious for this error. Try modify Set into List would solve this problem.

Hope this would help you.